# How to convert 2d to 3d piechart?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem, please give me some suggestion ?i want convert piechart 2d to 3d. Please help me.Please give me some idea.
chek the link.
this is follow link is [this is follow link is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/) 
[this is image of piechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsdRr.jpg)

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function () {

        var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Opp', 'Guess','Thre'],
            data = [ {
                y: 10.38,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Streanth'],
                    data: [70],
                    color: colors[2]
                }

            }, 
              {
                y: 5.38,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Streanth'],
                    data: [70],
                    color: colors[2]
                }

            }, 

              {
                y: 10.03,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Weakness'
                        ],
                    data: [30],
                    color: colors[1]
                }

            }],
            browserData = [],
            versionsData = [],
            i,
            j,
            dataLen = data.length,
            drillDataLen,
            brightness;


        // Build the data arrays
        for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

            // add browser data
            browserData.push({
                name: categories[i],
                y: data[i].y,
                color: data[i].color
            });

            // add version data
            drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
            for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
                brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
                versionsData.push({
                    name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                    y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                    color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
                });
            }
        }

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market share, January, 2015 to May, 2015'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com/">netmarketshare.com</a>'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total percent market share'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    shadow: false,
                    center: ['50%', '50%']
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Browsers',
                data: browserData,
                size: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                    },
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                data: versionsData,
                size: '80%',
                innerSize: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

this is html code

```
 <div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```js
$(function () {
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
            categories = ['Opp', 'Guess','Thre'],
            data = [ {
                y: 10.38,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Streanth'],
                    data: [70],
                    color: colors[2]
                }

            }, 
              {
                y: 5.38,
                color: colors[2],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Firefox versions',
                    categories: ['Streanth'],
                    data: [70],
                    color: colors[2]
                }

            }, 

              {
                y: 10.03,
                color: colors[1],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'Chrome versions',
                    categories: ['Weakness'
                        ],
                    data: [30],
                    color: colors[1]
                }

            }],
            browserData = [],
            versionsData = [],
            i,
            j,
            dataLen = data.length,
            drillDataLen,
            brightness;


        // Build the data arrays
        for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

            // add browser data
            browserData.push({
                name: categories[i],
                y: data[i].y,
                color: data[i].color
            });

            // add version data
            drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
            for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
                brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
                versionsData.push({
                    name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                    y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                    color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
                });
            }
        }


    
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 45,
                beta: 0,
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Browsers',
                data: browserData,
                size: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                    },
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                data: versionsData,
                size: '80%',
                innerSize: '60%',
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        // display only if larger than 1
                        return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
                    }
                }
            }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this.

```
$(function () {

            var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                categories = ['Strenth : 56', 'Weekness : 23'],
                data = [{
                    y: 20,
                    color: colors[0],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Strenth',
                        categories: ['Opp', 'Guess'],
                        data: [15, 5],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                },  {
                    y: 10,
                    color: colors[2],
                    drilldown: {
                        name: 'Threat',
                        categories: ['Wrong', 'Threat'],
                        data: [7, 3],
                        color: colors[2]
                    }
                },  ],
                totalData = [],
                subData = [],
                i,
                j,
                dataLen = data.length,
                drillDataLen,
                brightness;


            // Build the data arrays
            for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

                // add browser data
                totalData.push({
                    name: categories[i],
                    y: data[i].y,
                    color: data[i].color
                });

                // add version data
                drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
                for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
                    brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
                    subData.push({
                        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                        color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
                    });
                }
            }

            // Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: true,
                        alpha: 45,
                        beta: 0
                    }

                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total percent market share'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        shadow: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        depth: 45,

                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ''
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Total',
                    data: totalData,
                    size: '60%',
                    dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                        },
                        color: '#ffffff',
                        distance: -30
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'SUB',
                    data: subData,
                    size: '80%',
                    innerSize: '40%',
                    dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            // display only if larger than 1
                            return this.y > 0.5 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '' : null;
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/exporting.js"></script>
```